# SAP Table Connector - How to querying SAP table using RFC from Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, saprfc

We are using SAP Table Connector on Azure Synapse to extract SAP tables. However, we would like to filter the data in the copy activity.
I tried using the RFC table options using the COLUMN EQ 'SOME VALUE' pattern,

[image: Azure Synapse config field exemple]

This worked, but we would like to apply more filters like "AND" and "OR", like this "COLUMN EQ 'SOME VALUE' AND COLUMN1 EQ 'SOME VALUE' ", I don't know if this is possible, or if there are better ways to do this type of filter.

How can we overcome this issue?

Thanks for listening.

I tried with AND, &&, space, comma, but none worked, I think this might not be possible

Answer (score 0):

I feel like it should be possible to AND conditionals, but so far everything indicates it is not supported by default.  A custom function module would be able to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am also using the SAP Table Connector, and this is definitely possible. As an example I am getting table DD03L from SAP but I want to exclude rows that begin with certain things. Here is my query:

FIELDNAME NOT LIKE '.%' AND FIELDNAME NOT LIKE '$%' AND FIELDNAME NOT LIKE '#%'

Documentation for the SAP query operators can be found here: [Copy Activity Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-table?tabs=data-factory#copy-activity-properties)

The example you provided is correct and should work: "COLUMN EQ 'SOME VALUE' AND COLUMN1 EQ 'SOME VALUE'